# Why is scaling along the Z-axis affecting the shape of my beveled vertices?

Tags: edit-mode

I created a conveyer belt, but I realise I want the shape to be a bit smaller along the z-axes. So I want to edit the curve that the other shapes are bending around.
But when I try to do this, it is basically changing the shape of my whole object. As you can see in the pictures below. Why is that?

I want to keep the shape of the first image - the rounded edges.
I basically want to move the upper part down, so the shape also stays located at the world origin.

Here is the file: [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want smaller half-circles, you need the scale down the whole shape then move the right (or left) half part on the right (or left) so that it keeps its previous length

Comment: And if you want to keep the width of the curve and not adjust the length so that you can keep the _Array_ modifier as it is, you have to either reduce the _Count_ of the modifier to have less pieces that fit the curve's now shorter length, or you set the _Fit Type_ of the _Array_ modifier to _Fit Curve_, but then you might still have to adjust the _Relative Offset_ to keep a more or less even spacing between the pieces.